# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word in Plugin throws error " the containing assembly is not loaded as fully trusted"

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, office-interop

We are trying to implemented the functionality of "**Converting SharePoint Word document to pdf and saving that pdf in the SharePoint**".

For that purpose we are using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` in a `CRM 2011 Plugin`. The `plugin registration tool` is forcing us to register the plugin in `sandbox environment`. After we deployed the plugin we are experiencing below error:

> Message: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document'
>   from assembly 'WordToPdf, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=4c268052fda25dfb'. The type is marked as eligible for
>   type equivalence, but the containing assembly is not loaded as fully
>   trusted.

Can someone help us to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the WordToPdf assembly is not fully trusted, since the isolation mode of the plugin is set to `Sandbox`. Registering the plugin in Sandbox limits what the plugin can do, dll:s it can reference, etc. You probably need to find a way to set the isolation mode of the plugin to `None`, thereby removing the security restrictions that are currently imposed on your plugin.

One cause for only being able to register the plugin in Sandbox is that the user who tries to do the registration is not a CRM Deployment Administrator (not to be confused with system administrator...), which is a requirement.